# How to install intel-ucode on android OS?

Tags: android, virtualbox

folowing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX5aMWHAlPo

I try to install Android on VirtualBox

I get this error during the boot : `Failed to find cpu0 device node`

I am on Intel core i5 x64bit, Windows 10.

Some thread mention that i should install intel-ucode but how to do that ? there is no app-get in the shell

i veriffy that this package is missed with the command : `dmesg | grep microcode` it return nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the microcode update in the *host* operating system, and never in the guest operating system.  In fact, any non-joke hypervisor will refuse/block microcode update attempts.

So, you have to install the microcode update in Windows 10 and not in the Android guest.

This is likely to require the use of an unofficial VMWare microcode update driver.  The VMware microcode update driver for Windows is [here](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/vmware-cpu-microcode-update-driver).